# How to represent the cases to seat k people at a round table of size n?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I know the number of ways; $\cfrac{C(n,k)} {n} = \cfrac{(n-1)!} { k!\times(k-1)! }$ where $n=2k-1$. 
But I’m asking for the cases.

For example, 
when $(n,k)=(5,3)$, the number of ways is $2 = \cfrac{4!}{ 3!\times2!}$
and so, the $2$ cases are $\{(i,i+1,i+2), (i,i+1,i+3)\}$
( In order to understand easily, the cases are $\{(1,2,3), (1,2,4)\}$ when $i=1$. )

$2$ cases to seat $3$ people at a round table of size $5$:
[image: (picture) 2 cases to seat 3 people at a round table of size 5]

When $(n,k)=(7,4)$, the number of ways is $5 = \cfrac{6! }{ 4!\times 3!}$
and so, the $5$ cases are $\{(i,i+1,i+2,i+3), (i,i+1,i+2,i+4), (i,i+1,i+2,i+5), (i,i+1,i+3,i+4), (i,i+1,i+3,i+5)\}$

(the cases are $\{(1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,5), (1,2,3,6), (1,2,4,5), (1,2,4,6)\}$ when $i=1$. )

My question is how to represent the cases in general form to seat $k$ people at a round table of size $n$ ($n=2k-1$).

I want to know the references such as tutorial, URL, papers, etc.
If it is well known problem in math, even the name of the problem is helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.